# How can we allow microsoft single sign on only for .onmicrosoft.com?

Tags: node.js

We have used NodeJS quickstart for SSO using OpenID connect authentication. All domain logins allowed here. We just want to restrict login using .onmicrosoft.com. Can you please help us.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: OpenID is a protocol and you need to integrate with the providers (Microsoft, google, etc..) so you need to configure only the "login with Microsoft" button